# VBA Excel: Looping

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am currently trying to loop a column to find if a cell has a certain value. If the cell has that certain value it will search the row to find another value between a range. When that value in the range is found the final value of what "Name" that column in the range has, is given. When this is done, repeat it until no values in the first column is found.

I.E

- Loop through A:A to find X
- Look through range H:L to find Y
- Depending where Y was found, result in "M" out of {M,N,O,P,Q}
- Loop until no more X values are found in A:A

Would appreciate it very much if you could help me out with this!

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: "I am currently trying to loop a column to find if a cell has a certain value" -- why? Use the [Find method of a Range object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find). Looping cell by cell is usually not needed in Excel VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website to be very helpful for what you want to do:

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

I think you want something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim columns As Integer, rows As Integer

For i = 1 To rows
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = X Then
        For j = 1 To columns
            If Cells(i, j).Value = Y Then
                //Print out to M column
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```